# How to access codeigniter session from external files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to access codeigniter session from external files, so when i try to print session variables from external not have empty array

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter sessions are stored in a database table called `ci_sessions` unless you renamed it. Thus they are not accisible in the `$_SESSION` variable of PHP

heres what you do

1. get the session ID from the cookie. The cookie containing the session id will be called `ci_session` unless you changed the value of `sess_cookie_name` in the `config.php` file
2. from the database fetch the row from the `ci_sessions` table mentioned earlier and confirm that the clients `ip_address` and `user_agent` matches those in the row you just retrieved (this is for security reasons)
3. the actual session data will be held in the `user_data` column. You will have to parse this and obtain the key/value pairs. I suggest finding the relevant function for this in the sessions.php file in codeigniters system folder.